# Find a closed form of the power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let a power series $$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{4n+1},$$ then  $1$ is the radius of convergence of $S$ .In fact $S(x)$ convergens for each $x\in[-1,1).$
My work is to find a closed form of this power series.

---

The following is my solution:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(4n+1)x^{n}-4nx^{n}}{4n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}-4x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{x^{n}}{4n+1})^{'}.$$then we have $$S(x)+4x S^{'}(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}.(\text{a first-order linear differential equation })\Rightarrow $$ 
$$\mathbf{A.}\quad 
S(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}[C_{1}+\frac{\ln(1+x^{\frac{1}{4}})+2\arctan(x^{\frac{1}{4}})-\ln(1-x^{\frac{1}{4}})-4x^{\frac{1}{4}}}{4}](1>x>0);$$$$\mathbf{B.}\quad
 S(x)=-\frac{1}{8(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}\begin{Bmatrix}
C_{2}+8(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}\\+2\sqrt{2}\arctan[1-\sqrt{2}(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}]-2\sqrt{2}\arctan[1+\sqrt{2}(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}]\\+
\sqrt{2}\ln[1-\sqrt{2}(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{-x}]-\sqrt{2}\ln[1+\sqrt{2}(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{-x}]
\end{Bmatrix}\quad(-1\leq x<0).$$

Since $S(0)=0$ and $S(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ , I conclude that $C_{1}=C_{2}=0.$

---

I am not sure my solution is right .I need someone to check my answer,or If you   have some good ideas about how to solve this question ,please give me some hints.Any help is going to be appreciated!

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{4n+1}=_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},1;\frac{5}{4};x\right)-1=\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{x})}{2\sqrt[4]{x}}+\frac{\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{x})}{2\sqrt[4]{x}}-1$$

When $|x|$ is: zero or smaller than zero and $x$ is not 1

Comment: We sure do wish that exponent were $4n+1$, eh?  Howzabout setting $y = x^{1/4}$ and considering $yS(y^4)$.

Answer (score 15):

**Hint.** You may consider the following derivative 
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}\right)'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{4n}=\frac1{1-x^4},\quad |x|<1.
$$ Then, integrating the power series termwise  for $|x|<1$ (which is allowed), you get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}=\int_0^x\frac1{1-t^4}dt=\int_0^x\left(\frac{1}{4 (1-t)}+\frac{1}{4 (1+t)}+\frac{1}{2 \left(1+t^2\right)}\right)dt
$$ giving easily

> $$
> \sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}=\frac14 \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)+\frac12\arctan x-x, \quad |x|<1,
> $$

from wich you deduce your initial series by dividing first by $x$ then putting $x \to x^{1/4}$.

Comment: And $\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is also known as $\operatorname{artanh} x$.

Comment: @ccorn You are right. Thanks.

Comment: If you replace $x$ with $t^{1/4}$, the vaule of $x$ is  restricted to $[0,1).$  Maybe I  have not fully understand the meaning of  "putting $x\rightarrow x^{1/4}$."

Comment: It depends on what you want to obtain. If you want to keep things real, then of course you take the new variable $x \in [0,1)$. If you are considering complex numbers, you have **to choose which value** (principal or not) **is appropriate** for $z^{1/4}$ or $\log z$. But such a value **exists**. For example, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 \pm i \frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ are candidates for $(-1)^{1/4}$ since $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 \pm i \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\right)^4=-1$. One may just pick one of them.